Migrating Azure Function apps to AWS using containerized approach of EKS
I'm working on task where i need to convert/migrate Azure function apps running in Azure to AWS using the approach of containerizing the Azure function and depoly to EKS to achieve the same goal as Azure. Azure function does some control tasks like checking firewalls statuses to create incidents if any issues. I'm trying to figure out if this is possible by converting the Azure function into a docker image and depoly in AWS EKS and run. I'm trying to avoid of building the same code from scratch agian on aws as it is already built in azure. Any suggestions how can I proceed with this
Built the docker image and deployed in EKS and figuring out how to handle different tasks like ticket generation can I do it on AWS using EKS resources or do I need to handle it by code(python)

Certainly you can, but perhaps ECS or Lambda is more suitable in this case.
